# awk-- for each key in column one search all other columns and find minimum entry

Tags: perl, awk

I have a huge data file that looks like this (but with ~115 columns and something over 400 rows):

```
testing.txt

    agg10.cov   agg11.cov   agg12.cov   agg13.cov   
1:12418403  1.85E-01    4.20E-01    1.13E-01    3.27E-03    
1:23941533  3.07E-02    5.89E-04    1.92E-02    7.25E-01    
MC5R    3.32E-03    9.29E-02    3.89E-02    3.08E-01    
MC5R    1.80E-02    4.08E-02    3.51E-02    2.33E-01    
MC5R    1.17E-03    4.25E-03    2.88E-03    1.22E-02    
1:34128320  2.37E-02    1.64E-01    8.19E-03    2.88E-01    
1:35547072  2.18E-02    6.34E-02    3.47E-02    3.32E-02    
1:56    5.49E-02    6.14E-01    8.07E-01    1.82E-01    
1:56    2.98E-02    1.59E-02    2.60E-02    7.06E-01
```

For each entry in the first column, I need to search each of the remaining columns and take the minimum value for all rows that began with that entry. It needs to be scalable by the number of rows and columns without excessive re-entry of each column identifier if possible.

I haven't tried anything yet besides the min(if) in excel. That tends to break pretty quickly because its too much data for my computer to handle. I know a tiny bit of perl and itty bitty bit of awk.

I'm playing around with this, but I don't know how to make it scalable to a variable number of columns

```
awk 'NR==1{print;next}
{s[$1]=!s[$1]||$2<s[$1]?$2:s[$1];t[$1]=!t[$1]||$3<t[$1]?$3:t[$1];u[$1]=!u[$1]||$4<u[$1]?$4:u[$1]}
END{for(x in s)print x,s[x],t[x],u[x]}' testing.txt
```

Comment: You could do this in Perl. Just do `split /\s+/` for each line and then use the first element as a key to a hash and the value for the hash would be the minimum. You can just loop through the rest of the values in the array you get when you split the line to see if there is a new minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NF` returns the number of columns in a row, and you can refer to row `i` with `$i`. If you are using gawk, then there is multidimensional array (for minimum[column1][column_number]). If not, you can simulate it by concatenating column1 and column_number (which is implemented below).

```
{
    if (NR == 1) {
        print
        next;
    }

    column1s[$1] = 1;
    for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        key = i "::" $1
        if (!(key in min) || $i < min[key]) {
            min[key] = $i;
        }
    }
}

END {
    for (k in column1s) {
        row = k;

        for (i=2; i<=5; i++) {
            key = i "::" k;
            row = row "\t" min[key];
        }

        print row;
    }
}
```

Since it's a little long, you can put it in a file and call it like the following:

```
awk -f script.awk testing.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible Perl solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 'min';

my $file = 'testing.txt';
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Unable to open '$file' $!";

my @cols = split ' ', <$fh>;

my %data;
while (<$fh>) {
    my ($key, @vals) = split;
    push @{ $data{$key} }, @vals;
}
close $fh or die $!;

while ( my ($key, $aref) = each %data) {
    printf "%-12s %s\n", $key, min(@$aref);
}
```

List::Util has been part of perl core since v 5.08.

Output for this data set is

```
1:56         1.59E-02
1:34128320   8.19E-03
1:23941533   5.89E-04
1:35547072   2.18E-02
MC5R         1.17E-03
1:12418403   3.27E-03
```